# Simplifying large expression with Maxima

Tags: maxima, simplify

I would like to simplify al large expression using Maxima.
But when I do "ratsimp(eq1)" I recieve an error message.

PQUOTIENT: Quotient by a polynomial of higher degree (case 1)

Any ideas?

The expression is:

```
eq1: 0 = ((-(2*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                      -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*mB
     *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                      +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                      +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                   +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                   +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
      +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                      +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                      +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                   +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                   +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
      ^2)
/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
                ^2
               *(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                        +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                        +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                     +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                     +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                    *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                        +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                        +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                     +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                     +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                ^3))
+(2*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                  -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*R17_B*mB
 *((R13_B*mB)/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R13_A*mA)/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                 +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
                 ^2
                *(mB/((R13_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R13_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                *(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                 ^2)
+(2*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                  -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*R18_B*mB
 *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                 +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
                 ^2
                *(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                 ^2)
+(2*((-mB/((R13_B+1)^2*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                        +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                        +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                     +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                     +M_12C/(R13_B+1))))
  -((M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                    -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)
   *mB)
   /((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
               ^2))
 *((R13_B*mB)/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R13_A*mA)/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R17_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R17_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((mB/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
+mA/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
^2
*(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 ^2)
-(2*(mB/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                 +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  -(R13_B*mB)/((R13_B+1)^2*(2
                           *((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                           +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                           +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  -(R13_B*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                          -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*mB)
   /((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
               ^2))
 *((R17_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R17_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((mB/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                   +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
+mA/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
*(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 ^2)
-(4*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                  -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*mB
 *((R13_B*mB)/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R13_A*mA)/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R17_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R17_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R18_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R18_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                 +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
                 ^2
                *(mB/((R13_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R13_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                *(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                 ^3)
+(2*(M_13C/(R13_B+1)-(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)^2
                  -M_12C/(R13_B+1)^2)*R18_B*mB
 *((R13_B*mB)/((R13_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R13_A*mA)/((R13_A+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                            +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                         +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                         +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
 *((R17_B*mB)/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
  +(R17_A*mA)/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
              *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                  +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
               +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)+M_12C/(R13_A+1)))))
/((R18_B+R17_B+1)*(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                    +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                 +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)+M_12C/(R13_B+1))
                 ^2
                *(mB/((R13_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R13_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                *(mB/((R18_B+R17_B+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_B)/(R18_B+R17_B+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_B+R17_B+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_B)/(R13_B+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_B+1)))
                 +mA/((R18_A+R17_A+1)
                     *(2*((M_18O*R18_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +(M_17O*R17_A)/(R18_A+R17_A+1)
                         +M_16O/(R18_A+R17_A+1))
                      +(M_13C*R13_A)/(R13_A+1)
                      +M_12C/(R13_A+1))))
                 ^2))
/K48$
```